# Stand-alone SQL server data tool for visual studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Anywhere to download that tool without the visual studio 2013? I accidentally remove this tool and I really don't want to reinstall my visual studio 2013.

I searched vs->tools->extensions and updates; still can not find separate package.

Any good idea?

Comment: You'll need to install at least the VS 2013 shell in order to use SSDT. What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: SQL 2012 express, I mean I have installed the VS 2013, but I deleted the SSDT package accidentally, how can I retrieve it?

Comment: Are these the tools you are looking for? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about SSDT? I do think it is possible to remove SSDT from Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: But every time when I tried to use that tool, it popped out that the SSDT tool can not be loaded. Is that a conflict?